# Uncaught TypeError: Window.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

I tried to add an event listener on the DOM Window, however, it suggests that `Window.addEventListener` is not a function.

```
<script>
  Window.addEventListener('keydown',function (e){
    console.log(e);
  });
</script>
```

I expected the console to log the keydown event.

Comment: use `window` instead of `Window`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. It must be

```
//small 'w'
window.addEventListener('keydown',function (e){
  console.log(e);
});
```